# Illustrator: how to insert image into shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I downloaded a template and trying to add a picture into the shape. I can place it over the top but not into the curve. I have tried to select the picture and the outline and then "Clipping mask", but doesn't seem to work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to place your image over the shape and send it to back (or behind everything else) via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

The 'proper' way is to use a clipping mask, which involves more steps and can get confusing if you're new to Illustrator, but here goes:

- place your image on top of everything and position it where you need it
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Alt+Click</kbd> the curvy shape you're trying to use as a mask
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, which copies that shape as a new object in the same place
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to make sure this new shape sits on top of everything
- select both the image and the new shape and, with BOTH selected, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Lucian. This placed my image behind the "transparency" squares (which are also confusing to me). I understand about layers and trying to get used to buttons. Just cant seem to fit it to this template shape. I have edited my first image and added a screenshot with the outlines.

Comment: Thank you Lucian. Finally got it done. Slowly getting used to this software. Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 1):

The template was create so that it's confusing for people used with Photoshop that are used to seeing the 'pixel squares' when it's **nothing there** but that's not how Illustrator works. It doesn't show the same pixel squares when there's nothing to show, it just shows the color of your artboard which is white.

Therefore there's only one explanation, **the designer that created this template designed the squares as well, if you collapse your Layer you will certainly see A layer with your desired shape and with actual light-dark grey squares.**

That is why sending your image to the back does not produce the desired result.
Here's where the fun starts cause without seeing the layer tree that the template has it's hart to tell how the designer created it. So follow the following steps and you'll be fine.

- Keep double clinking on the squares to open each group till you can
  select each square individually.
- From there you can select all the squares, Copy (Ctrl+C) then exit
  all groups
- Create a new layer on top of the existing one and press Shift+Ctrl+V
  (paste in place, this pastes what you copied in the exact same
  position that you copied it from)
- And there you have it, the desired shape is in the new layer, from
  here on you can select Pathfinder > Unite to unite all the squares
  into a single shape, add your image and press Ctrl+7 for Clipping
  mask

> PRO TIP: The clipping mask doesn't work like in Photoshop. When using
>   clipping mask in illustrator, you must have your shape ON TOP of the
>   image, not behind.

Comment: Great help. Got it fixed and learned a lot. Think I will finally get my head around this!! Thank you to you both

Comment: @wesleywright Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as correct by ticking the check mark next to my answer if that's what fixed it